# 'No Ident response" and "Notice -- You need to identify via SASL to use this server" when attempting to connect to IRC with Roll Your Own Haskell Bot

Tags: haskell, irc

I am using [Roll Your Own IRC Bot](https://wiki.haskell.org/Roll_your_own_IRC_bot) on the Haskell wiki and I receive those two errors when running the code provided by the guide.

What is wrong? Why can't I connect?

I am using Ubuntu and I've tried compiling it with ghc and running it with ghci.

```
import Network
import System.IO
import Text.Printf

server = "irc.freenode.org"
port   = 6667
chan   = "#tutbot-testing"
nick   = "tutbot"

main = do
    h <- connectTo server (PortNumber (fromIntegral port))
    hSetBuffering h NoBuffering
    write h "NICK" nick
    write h "USER" (nick++" 0 * :tutorial bot")
    write h "JOIN" chan
    listen h

write :: Handle -> String -> String -> IO ()
write h s t = do
    hPrintf h "%s %s\r\n" s t
    printf    "> %s %s\n" s t

listen :: Handle -> IO ()
listen h = forever $ do
    s <- hGetLine h
    putStrLn s
  where
    forever a = do a; forever a
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `No Ident Response` notice refers to an hilariously antiqued protocol from the depths of Internet history.  In the olden days, when multi-user Unix machines were the rule rather than the exception, sometimes a server wanted to get some information on the specific user on the connecting client who had initiated the connection. The [Ident protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ident_protocol) was created for this purpose.  I guess IRC servers still contain code to try to query Ident servers, but they probably receive vanishingly few responses, so you can probably ignore this error.

The SASL error is more serious.  It suggests that the specific IRC server you're connecting to has been configured to require user identification and authentication via the SASL protocol before allowing a connection.  You probably don't want the added complexity of adding SASL support to your bot!

However, I'm not able to duplicate your problem.  When I run the code you've posted above, I connect to host `kornbluth.freenode.net [2001:1bc0:c1::6667/6667]`, see the notice about `No Ident response`, but my connection is accepted, as are the commands to set my nickname and join the `#tutbot-testing` channel, and I see the message of the day.  I also see messages from some poor soul (maybe you?) asking for help with his or her bot, but I can't respond because the tutbot code above can't send any commands!

Is it possible you were testing it using a difference `server` or `nick` than the one in the code above, and that's caused the problem?  If not, it's possible that there's a specific "irc.freenode.org" server that's configured to require SASL while the rest are working fine.  Try switching the server name to:

```
server = "kornbluth.freenode.net"
```

That seemed to work for me.

**Update:**  It looks like freenode requires SASL authentication from Amazon Web Services IP addresses (as noted in this [bug report for an IRC client](https://github.com/StackStorm-Exchange/stackstorm-irc/issues/1)), so that would explain the problem you're having.

Comment: Haha yes, that was me. I tried with multiple different servers and each time I receive the same message. Could it be something unique to Amazon Web Services which I and trying it through?

Comment: Yup, I added an update -- it looks like that's the problem.

Comment: Do you know how to implement SASL with Haskell? I don't mind learning about it.

Comment: There are `sasl` and `gsasl` packages, but neither looks to be in very good shape.

Comment: You don't really need SASL here. IRC uses PLAIN, which is just `username + "\0" + password` encoded as base64. To implement SASL, you have to send `CAP LS` before the initial `USER` command, and then a `CAP REQ :sasl` when you receive `CAP * LS :... sasl ...` line, after that you send `AUTHENTICATE base64(username+\0+password)` and finally a `CAP END`.